# Multiplying two sets of vectors in R

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose that I have two matrices A and B:

```
 A:      A1    A2        B:      B1   B2
   ROW1  V1    V2          ROW1  V3   V4
   ROW2  V5    V6          ROW2  V7   V8
```

I want to have a resulting matrix R that would include the products of each pair of the two matrices' columns like this:

```
 R:      A1_B1  A1_B2  A2_B1  A2_B2
   ROW1  V1*V3  V1*V4  V2*V3  V2*V4
   ROW2  V5*V7  V5*V8  V6*V7  V6*V8
```

A loop structure could do, but I wonder if there's better options available.

Comment: That gives you a 2x2 matrix!

Comment: Doh, thanks for pointing it out. Morning coffee, now.

Comment: `cbind(A[,1]*B, A[,2]*B)`?

Comment: How general do you think you might want this? More than one matrix? Matrices with different numbers of columns each?

Comment: That general that it applies to two matrices with arbitrary number of columns. Sven's solution seems to be correct for my purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `apply`:

```
A <- matrix(1:4,2,2)
#     [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4
B <- A * 10
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   10   30
# [2,]   20   40

matrix(apply(A, 2, "*", B), nrow = nrow(A))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   10   30   30   90
# [2,]   40   80   80  160
```

---

*ADDITION by Antti:*

This works wonderfully. In the end, I needed this for manipulating a `data.frame`. In order to apply meaningful column names for that `data.frame` I did following:

1. make that matrix a data.frame:

   ```
   R <- as.data.frame(R)
   ```
2. make vectors of column names in A and B

   ```
   Acol <- grep("A", names(data.frame(A)), value = T) 
   Bcol <- grep("B", names(data.frame(B)), value = T)
   ```
3. Then rename the columns of R:

   ```
   colnames(R) <- outer(Acol, Bcol, paste, sep = ".")
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First lets make some real data we can actually work with:

```
> A=matrix(c(1,5,2,6),2,2)
> B=matrix(c(3,7,4,8),2,2)
> A
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    5    6
> B
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    7    8
```

Now the problem is simply multiplying the right column combinations from A and B. Those combinations are A1, A1, A2, A2 times (respectively) B1 B2 B1 B2 - and we can get those combinations from `expand.grid`:

```
> cols = as.matrix(expand.grid(1:2,1:2))
> cols
     Var1 Var2
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    1
[3,]    1    2
[4,]    2    2
```

Then we get the columns of that as the columns of A and B (in the other order):

```
> A[,cols[,2]] * B[,cols[,1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    4    6    8
[2,]   35   40   42   48
```

QED

[Note how I carefully constructed A and B to match your V-numbers, so you can see that where you have V6*V8 I have 6*8]

Answer (score 0):

```
A <- matrix(1:4,2,2)
B <- A * 10

cbind(A[,1]*B, A[,2]*B)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   10   30   30   90
[2,]   40   80   80  160
```